# OpenXml Paragraph ForEach Docx

Tags: c#

I want to do something like the example below. I want to print my paragraphs in a loop, every time I get an error, I have no idea why. I wanted to ask you.

```
foreach (var d1 in model.dtable)
{
    new Paragraph(
        new ParagraphProperties(
            new Indentation() 
            { 
                Left = "0", 
                Hanging = "0" 
            }, 
            new ParagraphStyleId() 
            { 
                Val = "Normal" 
            }, 
            new Justification() 
            { 
                Val = JustificationValues.Both 
            },
            new NumberingProperties(
                new NumberingLevelReference() 
                { 
                    Val = 0 
                }, 
                new NumberingId() 
                { 
                    Val = 1 
                }
            ), 
            new Run(
                new RunProperties(
                    new Bold(), 
                    new FontSize() 
                    { 
                        Val = "22" 
                    }, 
                    new RunFonts 
                    { 
                        HighAnsi = "Arial" 
                    }, 
                    new RunFonts 
                    { 
                        Ascii = "Arial" 
                    }
                ),
                new Text(d1.name) 
                { 
                    Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve 
                }
            ), 
            new ParagraphProperties(
                new Run(
                    new RunProperties(
                        new FontSize() 
                        { 
                            Val = "22" 
                        }, 
                        new RunFonts 
                        { 
                            HighAnsi = "Arial" 
                        }, 
                        new RunFonts 
                        { 
                            Ascii = "Arial" 
                        },
                        new Text(" text2 ") 
                        { 
                            Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve 
                        }
                    )
                )
            )
        )  
    );
}
```

Comment: More help could be provided if you tell us the precise error you're getting, and where it occurs. Is it a runtime or Ccompile error? If it's not a compile error, then your issue is likely in the domain of OpenXML, and not C#, so a tag more suitable to the domain of the question is appropriate.

Comment: Definitely need to see the error. Also, I don't see how you're returning anything from this foreach. It seems to just create new instances of things. Each iteration of the foreach creates these objects and then goes to the next iteration, but you're not doing anything with the objects, so they'd just be lost. Maybe there's more context to be added to your example that would explain this?